# Combining two code snippets? Convert user input Youtube url to embed url and then replace iframe src with converted url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, iframe, youtube

I want the user to copy and paste their youtube url into input field, click submit button, and load that video above the input field. However, non-embed youtube urls don't work in iframes so they need to be converted using this regex.

Code I found for regex: http://jsfiddle.net/88Ms2/296/

This code works for html between two tags but I want to update the src attr of the iframe based on user input.

I was able to use this script to convert the input value to the iframe src but it is using the embed link, not the url at the top of the browser.

```
function getVid(){
    document.getElementById("vidSrc").src = document.getElementById("txtSrc").value;
    return false;
}
```

I need to somehow combine the two so that when the user pastes the youtube url in the text field, the url is converted to the embed code with the regex (if that is necessary) and then replace the iframe src with that input value.

Many thanks for any responses. I'm quite new and appreciate this site a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same regex, it would look something like this: [**(Updated example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/x5C37/)

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    function generate() {
        var input = $('#user_input').val();
        return input.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
    $('#video').html(generate());
});
```

Alternatively, here is another approach using pure JavaScript: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/rf869/)

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function() {
    function generate() {
        var input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
        return input.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
    document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = generate();
}
```

Comment: This works great! I ended up using the jQuery code and I changed the iframe height and width to 100% because I'm incorporating it into Bootstrap so it is responsive. Thanks a ton